# Integrating ModSecurity with nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I have compiled NGINX from source code and now I want to integrate ModSecurity. I have followed the steps mentioned in this website https://opsshield.com/help/cpguard/install-modsecurity-with-nginx-on-debian-ubuntu/
but i encountered i problem when i try to run the command like 'make modules', i get this error:
make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
i have followed the same steps, i'm using nginx 1.18.0, i'm stuck here, please someone helpe me, thanks.

`ubuntu@vps-622:/usr/local/src/cpg/nginx-1.18.0$ ls CHANGES  CHANGES.ru  LICENSE  Makefile  README  auto  conf  configure  contrib  html  man  objs  src ubuntu@vps-622:/usr/local/src/cpg/nginx-1.18.0$ make modules make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.`

Downloaded and compiled NGINX from source code.
cloned the ModSecurity Nginx Connector repository and built the module using the configure and make commands.

EDIT: now when i do 'sudo nginx -t' i get this error:

```
enter code hernginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "website.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf:39
```

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failede

I messed up, any help please

Answer (score 0):

If you use Debian or Ubuntu, you should try the pre-compiled packages from Digitalwave's repository: https://modsecurity.digitalwave.hu.